# How to keep to first boolean of consecutive group of values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to keep the `True` when it's isolated between 2 `False`, and keep the first `True` of a group of consecutive `True`.

What is a single ligne solution to do that ?

```
Date
2023-07-10 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-11 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-12 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-13 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-14 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-15 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-16 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-17 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-18 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-19 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-20 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-21 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-07-22 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-23 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-24 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-25 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-26 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-27 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-28 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-29 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-07-30 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-07-31 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-01 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-02 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-03 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-04 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-05 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-08-06 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-08-07 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-08-08 00:00:00+00:00     True
Freq: D, Name: Close, dtype: bool
```

Desired result would be:

```
Date
2023-07-10 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-11 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-12 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-13 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-14 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-15 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-16 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-17 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-18 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-19 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-20 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-21 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-07-22 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-23 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-24 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-25 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-26 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-27 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-28 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-29 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-07-30 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-07-31 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-01 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-02 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-03 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-04 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-05 00:00:00+00:00     True
2023-08-06 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-07 00:00:00+00:00    False
2023-08-08 00:00:00+00:00    False
Freq: D, Name: Close, dtype: bool
```

Comment: If change `2023-08-07 00:00:00+00:00` to `False` then in output `2023-08-08 00:00:00+00:00` should be `True` ?

Comment: @jezrael if only the index at 7 changes to False then yes, the next index remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain mask by original column with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) by inverted column by `~`:

```
df['Close'] = (df['Close'] & ~df['Close'].shift(fill_value=False))
print (df)
                         Date  Close
0   2023-07-10 00:00:00+00:00  False
1   2023-07-11 00:00:00+00:00  False
2   2023-07-12 00:00:00+00:00  False
3   2023-07-13 00:00:00+00:00  False
4   2023-07-14 00:00:00+00:00  False
5   2023-07-15 00:00:00+00:00  False
6   2023-07-16 00:00:00+00:00  False
7   2023-07-17 00:00:00+00:00  False
8   2023-07-18 00:00:00+00:00  False
9   2023-07-19 00:00:00+00:00  False
10  2023-07-20 00:00:00+00:00  False
11  2023-07-21 00:00:00+00:00   True
12  2023-07-22 00:00:00+00:00  False
13  2023-07-23 00:00:00+00:00  False
14  2023-07-24 00:00:00+00:00  False
15  2023-07-25 00:00:00+00:00  False
16  2023-07-26 00:00:00+00:00  False
17  2023-07-27 00:00:00+00:00  False
18  2023-07-28 00:00:00+00:00  False
19  2023-07-29 00:00:00+00:00   True
20  2023-07-30 00:00:00+00:00  False
21  2023-07-31 00:00:00+00:00  False
22  2023-08-01 00:00:00+00:00  False
23  2023-08-02 00:00:00+00:00  False
24  2023-08-03 00:00:00+00:00  False
25  2023-08-04 00:00:00+00:00  False
26  2023-08-05 00:00:00+00:00   True
27  2023-08-06 00:00:00+00:00  False
28  2023-08-07 00:00:00+00:00  False
29  2023-08-08 00:00:00+00:00  False
```